# Promoting your [app]s - advertising contest proposal

Tags: discussion, meta

I've proposed on Meta a contest for promoting StackApps applications developed with the API.
Please consider to leave your comments [over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/67272/is-it-possible-to-have-a-stackapps-advertising-sidebar-contest).  (Bounty **+250**)